# Change the plot line in the middle of the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this test plot

```
data <- data.table(c(1:20))
data[, key:=.I]
point <- c(5, 5)
ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = key)) + geom_line() + geom_point(aes(x = 5, y = 5))
```

which generates

[image]

I would like, **after** the point on the graph, to make the line dashed, using ggplot. Is it possible ?

Comment: Maybe `ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = key, linetype = as.factor(key > 5))) + ... ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the comment by zx8754, here is a sample solution, by sub-setting the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(c(1:20))
data[, key:=.I]
point <- c(5, 5)
data[, lineType1 := ifelse(key >= 5, "2", "0")]
g1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = V1, y = key)) + geom_line(data=data[key <= 5, ], linetype = "solid") +  
  geom_line(data=data[key >= 5, ], linetype = "dotted") + geom_point(aes(x = 5, y = 5))
g1
```

Sub-setting the data is the best way to get customized line plot. The interesting thing to note is the condition of sub-setting. I have used `data=data[key <= 5, ]` for 1st `geom_line()` and `data=data[key >= 5, ]` for 2nd `geom_line()`. This means that I am taking `key=5` in both the `geom_line()`.  The condition of sub-setting is done in such a way, so that there is no breaks between the two lines.

Hope the explanation is clear.